# How to notify my android app when something change in MySQL Database

Tags: android, mysql, database, servlets, triggers

I have a question about real time notification in MySQL.
I want that when there is a change in a specific table of the MySQL db, the db notify my android app that do something.

Is it possibile to do? I have listen that trigger can help, but i didn't found anything about that in web, especially for android.

I'm creating a real-time chat app for an android project at the university. It is required to use a servlet in the project, so my servlet makes requests to the database and sends the data to the app. To do this the app makes a GET request to the servlet every second to get the new messages. I would like to avoid making these requests and updating the message list only when there is a change in the database. I know it can be done with firebase for example, but having to use the servlet I would like to know if there is a way to notify the app when this change occurs.

The messages are insert in the db with a POST request to the servlet that update db; information about messages are taken from an edit text in the app and with a send button i make the request, so the thing that i have to do is to push the android app when new messages are detected in the db.

Comment: 1. Load all your messages in cache (HashMap etc.) at the servlet's startup in init method and make your android app access that cache. 2. whenever state of the mysql changes i.e someone adds new message, update that message in cache first so that your android app always use latest message data. 3. later update cache changes in database.    at last you asked that you want to notify the app so for that you can always use FCM notifications.

Comment: Ok, i already save db data in a cache in init method, but how can i use FCM notifications with my SQL db? @OnkarMusale

Comment: whenever the state of database changes i.e someone adds new message, you can send FCM notification to android app.

Comment: Ok, i understand what i have to do, but how i do it is the problem. I think that to send  this notification i can use a trigger in the db, but i don't know, i never used FCM notification before @OnkarMusale

Comment: ok it's getting too long. just tell me how the structure of your database is changing. how new messages are getting inserted. ? are using api to add or change the db structure if so. just add the Java FCM code after executing that insert message query. briefly explain it in your question by editing it.

Comment: Ok, i edit my question with these information @OnkarMusale

Answer (score 0):

'Is it possible?' questions are always difficult to answer.  The answer is almost always 'yes', but 'is it advisable', 'is it a good idea', 'is it recommended', that is where it gets more complicated.  I don't know of any way that a MySQL database change could notify individual Android app installations after a change.  However, a running instance of an Android app could poll the MySQL database and look for the structure of the table, and if the structure of that table differed from the last time it polled, it could do something.

This would have a large overhead, in having the app continuously polling the MySQL database to check the structure of the table.  That would add a lot of demands on your MySQL installation, eat up a lot of the app user's bandwidth and data plan.

So, 'is it possible', yes.  'is it recommended', no.

One question would be, what is the scenario where you think the table structure might change, and how often might that occur?  What many people do, is check to see a database's table structures only once, when the app starts up a new session.  If a change is detected on start-up, it could make the necessary local changes to its logic, then, assume the structure will remain constant through the rest of the session.  This would eliminate the constant polling and other negative behaviors I mentioned before.

Comment: I'm creating a real-time chat app for an android project at the university.
It is required to use a servlet in the project, so my servlet makes requests to the database and sends the data to the app.
To do this the app makes a GET request to the servlet every second to get the new messages.
I would like to avoid making these requests and updating the message list only when there is a change in the database.

I know it can be done with firebase for example, but having to use the servlet I would like to know if there is a way to notify the app when this change occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have some code component sending commands to the database. If yes, then that is where you could add code to post notifications to your app via websockets or something similar. Triggers in your database come at a cost and should be avoided if there is going to be a lot of them required.
As already mentioned, the app constantly polling, looking for a change is also expensive and probably best avoided.

Comment: I know it isn't a best practise, but i ask only if is it possible to do, and how to do it.